# bash: cut after n lines then concatenate horizontally

Tags: bash

I have a large ascii file which i want to reformat. The input format is:

```
a ; 1 ; 2 
b ; 2 ; 3 
c ; 4 ; 5 
d ; 6 ; 7 
e ; 8 ; 9 
f ; 10 ; 11
```

It has N=4 lines. The output format should be

```
a ; 1 ; 2; c ; 4 ; 5; e ; 8 ; 9
b ; 2 ; 3; d ; 6 ; 7; f ; 10 ; 11
```

So I want to cut n=2 consecutive lines and paste them horizontally potentially in a new result file.

How can I do this using bash?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried it using macros in vim, but its quite error prone, so I assume there should be a easier answer using bash, maybe loop over the file using an incrementing variable an horizontal paste to some resulting file

Comment: `n` is a constant here?

Comment: yes, n is constant

Comment: What if there are odd no. of rows?

Comment: What if the file has more than `2*n` rows?

Comment: file has many rows, every bunch of n lines need to be cut and paste horizontally to a result file

Comment: @mcExchange: You didn't get the Q - What if there are odd no of. rows? there won't another row to pair it with

Comment: The file has N lines in total, I want to cut n consecutive lines. N is divisible by n ( I updated the question)

Comment: You're looking for something like `awk -v n=2 '++i>n{i=1} {r[i]=r[i]s[i]$0;s[i]="; "} END{for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print r[i]}' file` but I'm too lazy to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk for that.

Awk processes its input files line by line and allows you to perform a wide range of operations each time. It supports arrays, so for the problem at hand, we can use an array in which we prepare the data in the correct format for the final output.

Initially, the array is empty. For the first `n` lines, all we have to do is store the line in a new row of the two-dimensional array. For your example, that gives us:

```
| a ; 1 ; 2 |
| b ; 2 ; 3 |
```

How did we construct this in awk? Conveniently, awk provides a special variable, `NR`, that always keeps the line number of the current line from the input file. So we can just use that variable to index the first dimension of our array, except that `NR` is 1-based, so we need to subtract 1 for 0-based indexing:

```
a[NR-1] = $0
```

Here, `$0` contains the contents of the current line in awk.

After the first `n` lines, we want to concatenate each new line to whatever is stored already in the array, always starting from the top again. So we need to take care of two things:

1. Computing the correct index for the array `a`
2. Performing a concatenation operation

The following line does both:

```
a[(NR-1)%n] = a[(NR-1)%n] "; " $0
```

Notice that the computation of the array index is now no longer `NR-1` but `(NR-1)%n` which uses the `mod` operator `%`. Concatenation is trivial: we just write the three parts to concatenate in sequence: 1) the previous array entry 2) the separator string `;` , and 3) again the current line.

However, we observe something interesting: thanks to the way awk treats uninitialized variables, we could almost use the above expression for the first `n` lines as well, since the `mod` does not change those values, and `a[(NR-1)%n]` would simply be the empty string when first used. The only problem is the separator string: we don't want that at the beginning of the line.

But there's a simple way around it: we can simply choose not to print it at the end. Then all that's left to do is this:

- For each line: `a[(NR-1)%n] = a[(NR-1)%n] "; " $0`
- At the end: print the contents of `a` but suppress the first two characters.

That's basically what the following script does, except if also trims whitespace off the beginning and end of each line (using `gsub`) and adds a little bit of convenience through the use of command line arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "USAGE: $(basename "${0}") <n> <file>+"
    exit 1
fi

n=${1}
shift

awk -v "n=${n}" '
{ gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", $0); a[(NR-1)%n] = a[(NR-1)%n] "; " $0 }
END { 
  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    print substr(a[i],3)
  }
}' ${@}
```

Comment: thx, it works. though I cannot really understand the solution. I assume it's too much to ask for a little explanation?(I always have the feeling that awk based solutions are not an easy read)

Comment: I added some explanations, and in doing so, I also adapted the code in the way @oguz_ismail suggested, using a 1-dimensional array with string concatenation instead of a 2-dimensional array, which makes the code much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my "non elegant solution" using parts of @Thomas answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

in_file=data.txt

# start at line 2
n=2
begin=$n
num_iterations=2

# first paste 2 starting lines to result file
head -n $n  $in_file > result.txt 

# then paste remaining 
for i in $(seq $num_iterations); do

    # increment starting line by 2
    let "begin+=$n"  

    # cut 2 lines and paste to temporary file
    head -n $begin  $in_file | tail -n $n | sed 's/ *# */ ; /' > tmp.txt  
    
    # concat results horizontally
    paste -d '; ' result.txt tmp.txt > result_tmp.txt;  
    
    # update result file
    mv result_tmp.txt result.txt  

done
```

Better try understand the non-explained solution by @oguz ismail

```
awk -v n=2 '++i>n{i=1} {r[i]=r[i]s[i]$0;s[i]="; "} END{for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print r[i]}' file
```